# compare 2 arraylist in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

i want to campare 2 arraylist  and show the values ..

```
arraylist1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

arraylist2 = {2,4,5}
```

i have compare and the value to listview .. like this

```
1  Not available
2  available
3  Not available
4  available
5  available
6  Not available
```

i write the program like this but looping  many times ..

```
 For position As Integer = 0 To arraylist1.Count - 1
  Dim words As String() = arraylist2(position).Split(New Char() {" "c})
    arr(1) = words(3)
    For i = 0 To arr.Length - 1
     If arraylist1(i).Contains(arr(1)) Then
        arr(0) = i
        arr(2) = "working"
        itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
        lv1.Items.Add(itm)
     Else
        arr1(0) = i
        arr1(1) = arrproc(i)
        arr1(2) = "NOT working"
        itm = New ListViewItem(arr1)
        lv1.Items.Add(itm)
     End If
   Next
 Next
```

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` anymore but a generic list, in this case a `List(Of Int32)`

Comment: What do you show when the item exists in list2 but not in list1?

Comment: are the arrayLists always sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Tim was suggesting use List(Of Integer)

kind of like this

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
Dim list2 As New List(Of Integer) From {2, 4, 5}

        For Each i As Integer In list1

            If list2.Contains(i) Then

                Console.WriteLine(i & " available")
            Else

                Console.WriteLine(i & " Not available")

            End If

        Next
```

also in your code within the first loop, you use the index of arraylist1 in arraylist2 to get the words this will fail if both lists don't have the same amount of items and will run into an out of bounds exception

**EDIT**

So there are a few more problems to solve i guess

- you loop over the arraylist1 to retrieve items from arraylist2
- you use the forth word of that items and assign it to a random array (arr())
- then you loop over that random array and compare the second item in
  that array with all item from the arraylist1 at the indices of that
  random array

so my suggestion is to review your code again

this might work but still some questions to answer

```
For Each item_list1 As String In arraylist2
            Dim words As String() = item_list1.Split(New Char() {" "c})
            If arraylist1.contains(words(3)) Then
                itm = New ListViewItem(arraylist1.IndexOf(words(3)))
                itm.SubItems.Add(words(3))
                itm.SubItems.Add("working")
            Else
                itm = New ListViewItem(arraylist1.IndexOf(words(3)))
                itm.SubItems.Add(arrproc(arraylist1.IndexOf(words(3))))
                itm.SubItems.Add("NOT working")
            End If
            lv1.items.add(itm)
        Next
```

Comment: can you give you real world example, where you split the values of one array list and what does the arrprc(i) function do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use such linq query to compare those lists and return the appearance status of items of first list in seccond list:

```
Dim list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
Dim list2 = {2, 4, 5}
Dim data = list1.Select(Function(item)
                 Return New With
                 {
                    .Value = item,
                    .Status = String.Format("{0} {1}", item, IIf(list2.Contains(item), "Available", "Not Available"))
                 }
                 End Function).ToList()
```

Then you can simply add them to `ListView` this way:

```
For Each item In data
    Me.ListView1.Items.Add(item.Value.ToString()).SubItems.Add(item.Status)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Full example

```
Sub Main()

        Dim list1 As New List(Of Integer)() From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
        Dim list2 As New List(Of Integer)() From {2, 4, 5}

        Dim rows = From i In list1
                    Group Join j In list2
                    On j Equals i Into g = Group
                    From j In g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    Select i, j


        For Each r In rows
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", r.i, If(r.i = r.j, "exist", "not exist"))
        Next


        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```